# Batch not running from Console

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a batch file `foo1.bat` containing this:

```
@echo off
  echo.>"\\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\dblank.txt"
```

If I double-click the file then `dblank.txt` gets created as expected.

In my `Console App` I've tried two different approaches:

1.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\foo1.bat");
```

2.

```
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
Process process;
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","/c \\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\foo1.bat");
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = aPath;
process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Neither of the above throws an exception but neither creates the expected output file:

If I change the code inside `foo1.bat` to something like the following and create a corresponding empty file `bar.txt` then it runs ok via the console and the text is written to `bar.txt` as expected:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
(
    systeminfo | findstr .... 
    echo %a%
    echo %b%
    echo %c%
) > "%~dp0\bar.txt"
```

Comment: Does the 2nd string literal parameter to the `ProcessStartInfo` constructor really not begin with an `@`? Otherwise your backslashes are going to be gobbled up.

Comment: Also, have you tried running `cmd` with the `/k` parameter so that the shell persists and you can view any reported errors?

Comment: @wardies testing your changes now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code work for me:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\execute.bat";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
```

check shared folder permissions

this works too  `p.StartInfo.FileName = "\\\\xxxx\\xxx\\execute.bat"`;

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you need some more double-quotes in this line:

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","/c \\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\foo1.bat");
```

Your second parameter is quoted, which makes sense, but you're starting a new process with `cmd /c` and then feeding it `\\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\foo1.bat` which contains a space.

That means you're really telling `cmd` to execute `\\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt` with an argument of `Files\foo1.bat`.

So you're going to have to add quotes around that part of the argument as well.  You can build up the string or just put pairs of double quotes, or as you did in your first option, use the `@` sign.  I would probably just do this:

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","/c ""\\xxx\xxx$\xxx\xxxx\xxxx\BATScipt Files\foo1.bat""");
```

where `""` is an embedded `"` in a double-quoted string.